# PHP GET error $

Tags: php

I want to collect information from http://mywebsite1.com/register.php?log=firstname=Yoga&lastname=Galih

but i want to get that info to my 2nd website using PHP $_GET and save it to `reg.log`

```
<?php
$txt = "reg.log"; 
if (isset($_GET["log"]) && isset($_GET["firstname"]) && isset($_GET["lastname"]) && isset($_GET["address"]) && isset($_GET["city"]) && isset($_GET["state"]) && isset($_GET["zip"]) && isset($_GET["country"]) && isset($_GET["phone"]) $$ isset($_GET["gender"]) && isset($_GET["haircolor"]) && isset($_GET["eyecolor"]) && isset($_GET["high"]) isset($_GET["weight"])) {
    $firstname = $_GET["fname"];
    $lastname = $_GET["lname"];
    $address = $_GET["address"];
    $city = $_GET["city"];
    $state = $_GET["state"];
    $zip = $_GET["zip"];
    $country = $_GET["country"];
    $gender = $_GET["gender"];
    $haircolor = $_GET["hcolor"];
    $eyecolor = $_GET["ecolor"];
    $high = $_GET["high"];
    $weight = $_GET["weight"];
    $phone = $_GET["phone"];
    echo $firstname .PHP_EOL. $lastname .PHP_EOL. $address .PHP_EOL. $city .PHP_EOL. $state .PHP_EOL. $zip .PHP_EOL. $country .PHP_EOL. $phone .PHP_EOL. $hcolor .PHP_EOL. $ecolor .PHP_EOL. $high .PHP_EOL. weigh .PHP_EOL. gender;
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
fclose($fh); // Close the fil
}
?>
```

but I get error [21-Mar-2016 15:17:09 America/New_York] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$' in /home/my2ndweb/public_html/includes/register.php on line 3

I need help

Thanks

Comment: You forgot the && before isset($_GET["weight"]

Comment: Put them all in one `isset`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php `If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.`

Comment: **Syntax errors:** use a proper IDE like Netbeans or PHPStorm

Comment: Also, you don't have to use isset, just the variable itself will return the same result.

Comment: The URL you say you want to use don't meet your conditional..

Answer (score 3):

Wow the line in question is very long. I'm not one for sticking to 80 characters, but that's unreadable.

The problem is on line 3 you have `$$` instead of `&&`. You are also missing another `&&` near the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

on line 3:

```
    $$ isset($_GET["gender"])
```

should be:

```
    && isset($_GET["gender"])
```

also at the end it should be

```
    && isset($_GET["weight"])
```

It looks like you will also have problems with your echo because you are calling variables that don't exist, ie $ecolor should be $eyecolor as that is your variables name

Comment: He also forgot to add the && before isset($_GET["weight"]

Comment: yeah just saw that, long line to look through

Answer (score 0):

`"$$ isset($_GET["gender"])"` on line 3
should be `"&&isset($_GET["gender"])"` on line 3

Comment: how to make it simple?

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace the double $$ with && isset($_GET["gender"]) and you forgot the && before isset($_GET["weight"]

Comment: but reg.log still empaty